# Android: How to display first three items in listview and rest within scroll

Tags: android, listview

[image]Currently i am displaying listview using visibility "GONE" and then "VISIBLE" on button click, But its displaying only 1 item in listview, other elements in scrollview ( i need to scroll), so i decided to keep listview showing atleast 3 items first and rest element on listview scroll.
how to work out this, thanks in advance.

1st image is my code
i need to have like 2nd image

Answer (score 4):

A ListView inside a ScrollView is a bad idea in general.

Instead you should use a LinearLayout and inflate your ListItems in there.
Not too hard to do. Just use a for loop or something.
If you MUST use a ListView you can call the following method on your ListView after it has been populated.

(change listAdapter.getCount() to the number of cells you want to show

```
 public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```